# Does someone know how to solve this C# Math Algorithm?

Tags: c#

Does someone know how to solve this C# Math Algorithm?

The control number calculates by multiplying each number in a "social security number"  with changing 2 and 1 (starting with 2). Then it calculates and adds together.

The control number should be equal divided with 10 to be correct and pass.

Ex, 720310-1212 "Social security number"

```
7* 2 = 14  --> 1+4

2* 1 = 2   --> 2 

0* 2 = 0   --> 0

3* 1 = 3   --> 3

1* 2 = 2   --> 2

0* 1 = 0   --> 0

1* 2 = 2   --> 2

2* 1 = 2   --> 2

1* 2 = 1   --> 2

2* 1 = 2   --> 2
```

Then add them 1+4+2+0+3+2+0+2+2+2+2 = 20

20/10 = 2 Pass!

Comment: Looks like you want to validate the Swedish "personnummer"?

Answer (score 11):

You need:

- a counter to accumulate the numbers,
- a loop to iterate over the input string,
- [`char.GetNumericValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k33ktz.aspx) to get the numeric value of each input character,
- a boolean flag that is changed each iteration to indicate whether to multiply by 1 or 2,
- the modulus operator `%` to calculate the remainder of the division by 10 at the end.

Should be simple enough. Homework?

---

**Edit**

LINQ solution:

```
var valid = "720310-1212"
    .Where(c => char.IsDigit(c))
    .Select(c => (int)char.GetNumericValue(c))
    .Select((x, i) => x * (2 - i % 2))
    .Select(x => x % 10 + x / 10)
    .Sum() % 10 == 0;
```

Comment: It may be homework, but not necessarily; the given sample data looks like the Swedish counterpart of a social security number, and they are quite frequently used by various authorities and organizations as a sort of "customer number", so it's a rather common case that you wish to validate them (which is done according to the described algorithm). There does seem to be a student-ish age reference in the OP's nick name though...

Comment: Okay. In case it's not homework I added a LINQ solution. No lecturer will give any points for this solution if it doesn't come with two pages of documentation :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're describing the [Luhn algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) (also known as mod 10).  It's used to validate credit cards (and other things).  There is a C# implementation at [E-Commerce Tip: Programmatically Validate Credit Card Numbers](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_security/authentication/article.php/c12283/).